# how to transfer a file to my server directly from another server

Tags: linux, download

Hey guys what is the easiest way to transfer a file to my server directly from another server, this way I won't download the file to my pc and then upload it to my server, so the requested file should look like http://www.examplesite.com/file.zip
my server is running linux, but I don't have SSH access.

So how can I do this ?
and thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a shell on your server. Then try :

```
man wget
```

And use :

```
wget http://www.examplesite.com/file.zip
```

If you can not have acces to a shell then tell us exactly what control you have over your server.

my2c

Comment: This assumes you have access to a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Without SSH it will be very difficult. Possibly rsync might work, if its on both servers with damons set up. RCP (remote copy) exists, its simlar to SCP with out the SSH part, but I doubt its installed due to security concerns.

Comment: Do you have any form of shell access? Thats an important bit of information.

Comment: No my hosting plan doesn't include shell access

Comment: Without shell access I'm afriad you are limited to ftp'ing the file down to your local machine, and then back up to the destination server. If you had shell access to the source server you could ftp directly from the source to destination server. But without any shell access you are in a hard situation.